# Is it possible to have tabs in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I often need to open many finder windows at the same time and my desktop becomes cluttered.

Is there any way to get tabs in Finder so one window can host multiple folders?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: As shown in File Menu and being consistent with the rest of the macOS shortcuts, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open a new tab. Tabbed Finder was introduced in OS X Mavericks in 2013.

With the native Finder app that comes with OS X is not possible to have tabs.
If you really need them you can use some Finder replacement app, like [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) or [PathFinder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) (both not free).

Comment: I wouldn't classify TotalFinder a "replacement", but PathFinder sure seems like a replacement and consequently comes with a slight learning curve. TotalFinder is simple in that it only adds one real big feature; tabs. A recent update has also added cut & paste. The other features are relatively minor and most folks won't touch them.

Comment: @Randy6T9 One added feature I like about TotalFinder is "Folders on Top".

Answer (score 6):

[TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) "brings tabs to your native Finder". It's commercial software, however. There are some other Finder replacements as well.

Answer (score 5):

Mavericks (MacOS X 10.9) brings us native tabs in the Finder (finally).

Answer (score 4):

A free alternative for OS X 10.6.8 to 10.8.2 is also [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/), which supports Tabs as well.

Answer (score 3):

it was already mentioned but PathFinder is an incredible app.  Plus there is a mac bundle site with it on discount right now.  [MacPromo Bundle](http://www.macpromo.com/)

Answer (score -3):

IMO, I would wait before buying any program/app, as the new OS from apple, aka: lion, will probably address the finder and its shortcomings.